# Having troubles getting data from List Adapter for OnItemClick

Tags: java, android, string, android-listview, listadapter

Im having an issue with getting data that is obtained when my listadapter is set to my listview. Im trying to get this data in `onItemClick` so that i can put it into my intent extra's for my other activity to obtain.

## The Problem

Currently i've created null string variables and then in my adapter assigning the strings with the desired text by methods within my model. However the problem im having is that the **text** that is being pulled is *not the correct text* for the position that onitemclick was called for.

Here some code...

### XMLParseActivity

```
public class XMLParseActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

 private ListView mIssueListView;
 private IssueParser mIssueParser;
 private List<IssueFeed> mIssueList;
 private IssueAdapter mIssueAdapter;

 private String result_connectedtype = "";
 private String result_symptom = "";
 private String result_problem = "";
 private String result_solution = "";
 private String result_comments = "";
```

...

```
public class IssueAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<IssueFeed> {
    public List<IssueFeed> issueFeedList;

    public IssueAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<IssueFeed> issueFeedList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, issueFeedList);
        this.issueFeedList = issueFeedList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        IssueHolder issueHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = View.inflate(XMLParseActivity.this, R.layout.issue_list_item, null);
            issueHolder = new IssueHolder();
            issueHolder.issueConnectedType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_connected_type);
            issueHolder.issueSymptomView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_symptom);
            view.setTag(issueHolder);
        } else {
            issueHolder = (IssueHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        IssueFeed issueFeed = issueFeedList.get(position);
        issueHolder.issueConnectedType.setText(issueFeed.getConnected_type());
        issueHolder.issueSymptomView.setText(issueFeed.getSymptom());

        //THE DATA I WANT TO USE IN MY INTENT
        result_solution = issueFeed.getSolution();
        result_comments = issueFeed.getComments();
        result_connectedtype = issueFeed.getConnected_type();
        result_problem = issueFeed.getProblem();
        result_symptom = issueFeed.getSymptom();

        return view;
    }
}

static class IssueHolder {
    public TextView issueSymptomView;
    public TextView issueConnectedType;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long id) {

    //Put the strings in intent extra
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SpecificIssueActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("symptom", result_symptom);
    intent.putExtra("problem", result_problem);
    intent.putExtra("solution", result_solution);
    intent.putExtra("comments", result_comments);
    intent.putExtra("connectedtype", result_connectedtype);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The listAdapter is set in a asynctask in the below code

```
public class DoLocalParse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<IssueFeed>> {
    ProgressDialog prog;
    String jsonStr = null;
    Handler innerHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        prog = new ProgressDialog(XMLParseActivity.this);
        prog.setMessage("Loading....");
        prog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<IssueFeed> doInBackground(String... params) {
        mIssueParser = new IssueParser(null);
        mIssueList = mIssueParser.parseLocally(params[0]);

        return mIssueList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<IssueFeed> result) {
        prog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mIssueAdapter = new IssueAdapter(XMLParseActivity.this, R.layout.issue_list_item,
                        mIssueList);
                int count = mIssueAdapter.getCount();
                if (count != 0 && mIssueAdapter != null) {
                    mIssueListView.setAdapter(mIssueAdapter);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my model `IssueFeed` looks like this

```
public class IssueFeed implements Serializable {

private String connected_type;
private String symptom;
private String problem; 
private String solution; 
private String comments; 

public IssueFeed() {
}

public IssueFeed(String connected_type, String symptom, String problem, String solution, String comments) {
    this.connected_type = connected_type;
    this.symptom = symptom;
    this.problem = problem;
    this.solution = solution;
    this.comments = comments;
}

public String getConnected_type() {
    return connected_type;
}

public String getSymptom() {
    return symptom;
}

public String getProblem() {
    return problem;
}

public String getSolution() {
    return solution;
}

public String getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setConnected_type(String connected_type) {
    this.connected_type = connected_type;
}

public void setSymptom(String symptom) {
    this.symptom = symptom;
}

public void setProblem(String problem) {
    this.problem = problem;
}

public void setSolution(String solution) {
    this.solution = solution;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}
}
```

Comment: Why to pass the data the adapter? If you have the model defined, then you can just get the data from your main class right. Please correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @mike20132013 Yeah i guess your right, I guess im just unsure on the best approach to getting the data. Right now as you can see in the adapter code, my IssueFeed and issueFeedList are defined so im able to use the methods in the model to pull the data. Would you recommend a alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the issue by getting the data from some simple methods in my model to obtain the values.